# Google Appengine problem with SVN repositry

Tags: eclipse, svn, google-app-engine, subclipse

Hello there stackoverflow,
I have a Google Appengine project.
I've decided to SVN it.

I get an error I've never seen from the Google Appengine:

- com.google.appengine.tools.info.LocalVersionFactory getVersion
- INFO: Could not find API version from E:\ws\msgServ\war\WEB-INF\lib.svn
- java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\ws\msgServ\war\WEB-INF\lib.svn (Access is denied)

It seems to be looking for a '.svn' file under the project's 'WEB-INF\lib' directory.
Of course, being version-controlled, it has a '.svn' subdir to each directory of the project, including the above mentioned directory.

Does any1 know how to circumvent this?
I may point out, that this project did *not* begin as a version controlled one, but as a regular GAE project.
I then created a proper repository, and drag-dropped all project files by hand.

(I'm using Eclipse, with Subclipse and the GAE plugin)

Suggestions?
David

Comment: Smells some user permissions issue

Comment: @Gopi,
Well... I am admin on the system, so I can take control.

The whole Workspace, is OPEN for both read/write.

So if some subdir ('.svn') is locked, it means some1 locked it...

My main fear is, that Subclipse (the SVN plugin) locked this folder for itself. And if it did so, I imagine it did it, for a good reason. That's why I don't want to "manually" unlock the dir.

I will try opening it for reads only.

Comment: RE@Gopi
I've opened the folder for READ only - did not work.
I've then opened it for WRITE as well, did not work.
Each time, when I launch the project again, the folder becomes protected again. I guess the Subclipse plugin, just jump and changes the attributes. So this won't go.
What I'm currently aiming at, is a way to make GAE not look into a directory.